# How to prevent duplicate notifications in Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently implementing a Chat application using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notifications. Using the `notification` field in the API call, Firebase displays them automatically without having to manually create a service and listen for the messages.

The push notification is pretty generic, just says "You have a new message!", so it doesn't make sense to keep adding new pushes every new message, I need firebase to not show a new push if the message body contents the same of a previous one.

Is it posible to do without implementing the service and handling Notification show manually? Found no references of this use case in the documentation.

Comment: if you want to do things manually you need to use the service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application is in Foreground then you receive the notification in `onReceive` of your FirebaseMessagingService. Else notification is delivered to system notification tray. Since you don't know the id of the notification so you may not retrieve it. It is also possible that your application is not running at the time you receive the notification. So logically it is **NOT** possible even by implementing the service. Well you can solve the problem by another approach. You can use **Firebase  Database** in conjuction with **Cloud Functions**. Just  have a look on [developer guide of cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) and you will find that they can help yourself achieve you what you want. As a solution skeleton : Post messages to Firebase Database and Send notification using cloud functions. When the recipient reads the message update the database to reflect message has been read like having a variable seen. Design your cloud function such that it reads the value of seen value of last message and sends notification only if it was true. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I read a lot about the Cloud Functions, and I was hoping I could do some configurations in the application to avoid using it. Maybe the best approach is to handle it in the API sending, maybe putting an unique hash in each push notification before sending to Firebase.

Answer (score 4):

For manual handling you have to use the service. Go for **handleIntent(intent)** of **FirebaseMessagingService**. 
This method gets called when application is in foreground, background and killed state. To avoid the duplication, do not call **super.handleIntent(intent)**. This will prevent the automatic push notification when app in BG or killed state.

This worked for me.